# Usar Versões Prévias do SDK e do .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

Ao tentar Criar um Projeto no Visual Studio(Aplicativo do Console[.NET Core]) retorna o seguinte erro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao realizar as alterações conforme solicitado o erro persiste
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Reiniciei o Visual Studio várias vezes e também o computador.
Tentei também instalar: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.3-windows-x64-installer
Não obtive sucesso em nenhuma tratativa, e o erro persiste.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Qual versão você está tentando criar e quais sdks você tem instalados na sua máquina? Inclua em sua pergunta os passos anteriores à mensagem de erro.

Comment: Leandro, estou aprendendo a programar. Poderia me dizer como posso validar as informações que você pediu?

Comment: No prompt de comando, execute o seguinte comando `dotnet --list-sdks`

Comment: Informa que "dotnet" não é um comando reconhecido.
Estranho, pois acabei de instalar o ASP .NET Core 3.1.3

Comment: Meu caro, eu fiz a instalação incorreta do SDK.
Após instalar corretamente o problema foi resolvido.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/sdk-3.1.201-windows-x64-installer

Comment: então acho que é válido fechar a pergunta ;)